# Green's function for coupled ODEs or system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

Is there any general formulation to find Green's functions of coupled ODEs or a system of ODEs?

What is **'Green's function matrix'**? Do Green's functions of coupled ODEs form a matrix which is called **Green's function matrix**?

Please refer to a good text in this regard.

Comment: if you know what is Green function of $y'=f(x,y)$ now consider $y$ is a vector and you have $y'=Ay$ with $A$ matrix in this case the Green function will be a matrix. In general green function is an inverse operator, i.e. if $Lu=f$ then $Gf=u$

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky It will be helpful if you kindly provide a small example.